# I am trying to push data into my db using JpaRepository but there was some error stopping me to do so

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
    *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START ***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.Lex.Exercise.Service.RegistrationService required a bean of type 'com.Lex.Exercise.Repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.Lex.Exercise.Repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

//UserRepository

```
package com.Lex.Exercise.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.Lex.Exercise.Model.UserEntity;

  public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, String>{

  }
```

//RegistrationService

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.Lex.Exercise.Repository")
@Component
public class RegistrationService {  
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
//business methods and other validations comes here
}
```

> This is the main class

```
    package com.Lex.Exercise.SpringBootDemo;
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:configuration.properties" })
public class SpringBootDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationService service;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> Below is the project structure:
>   /SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Model/User.java
>   /SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Model/UserEntity.java
>   /SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Repository/UserRepository.java
>   /SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Service/RegistrationService.java
>   /SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/SpringBootDemo/SpringBootDemoApplication.java
>   /SpringBootDemo/src/main/resources/application.properties
>   /SpringBootDemo/src/main/resources/configuration.properties

Please help me how I could resolve this

Comment: Please provide your project structure

Comment: /SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Model/User.java
/SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Model/UserEntity.java
/SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Repository/UserRepository.java
/SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/Service/RegistrationService.java
/SpringBootDemo/src/main/java/com/Lex/Exercise/SpringBootDemo/SpringBootDemoApplication.java
/SpringBootDemo/src/main/resources/application.properties
/SpringBootDemo/src/main/resources/configuration.properties

SpringBootDemoApplication.java is the main class

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@ComponentScan(scanBasePackages = "com.Lex.Exercise.Repository")` on your `RegistrationService.class`

And your `SpringBootDemoApplication.class` should look like this. Than your components in subpackages of `com.Lex.Exercise` will be injected into the Application context.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.Lex.Exercise"})
public class SpringBootDemoApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(SpringBootDemoApplication.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

In general it is a good idea to put the SpringApplication in the top level package (like in your case `com.Lex.Exercise`) because Spring Boot scans automatically all subpackages of that class. So you wouldn't need the extra `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working fine now when I moved my main class to the top level package com.Lex.Exercise.

Comment: @RANADHEERSANNIHITH if this answer helped you in any way you should upvote it. And if it solved your problem, please accept it. This will help others see that a) the question is answered, b) identify the important, i.e. helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.Lex.Exercise.Repository")` belongs on your configuration, which might be your application class

Comment: you mean @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.Lex.Exercise.Repository") should be mentioned in my main class?

Comment: Yes. At least thats my first guess. If that doesn't work we probably need more information about how your app is set up (pom.xml, the main application class)

Comment: updated the main class and the project structure in the post itself. Please check and help @Jens Schauder